# Show a custom popup if someone doesn't have the required .NET-framework to run an application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I built an application for version 4 of the framework. When I try to run it it says:

> In order to run the application, you have to install the following version of the .NET-framework first: v4.0 [...]

That already isn't too bad but it would be great to display a custom message, maybe even with a link to the latest version of the framework.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no straight-forward way of customizing this message. In fact, the message about the unsupported version of the framework is coming from mscoree.dll (i.e. the version of mscoree.dll present on the system).

What you can do is write your own launcher in C++, that will first check whether the required framework version is installed, possibly display a custom message and then [host the CLR](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/simpleclrhost.aspx) inside the launcher.

Comment: Would you really need to host the CLR? I think a simple Process.Start (equiv) would do.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Sure it would; but I think such a mechanism only makes sense if you want to deploy a single file to the user (instead of using the recommended installer/bootstrapper approach). For example, what happens if users double-click the actual .NET assembly and not my launcher? Then all my customization was in vain.

Comment: using the `Process.Start()` approach also goes against the grain with Win7.  If your user wants to pin your application to their task-bar, for example, they would have to pin the launcher which would close nearly immediately.  Having your startup .exe running for the duration of the application is much more intuitive

Answer (score 1):

If your application uses a Windows installer package (Wix) then consider listing the framework as a prerequisite, which will let the installer do the check for you and also offer the user the chance to download the framework.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best installation mechanism, but if you create a ClickOnce installer you can set the required .NET framework for your application and it will download and install it if it's not present on the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but what platform should the message use?

You would need a bootstrapper, a wrapper that checks and then starts your App.

You could bootstrap with a .NET 2 application if you can assume that Fx2 is installed. But in the future you might see PC's that have Fx4 but not Fx2.

So you will need an unmanaged wrapper to cover the widest range of possibilities.